# Unable to declare a class field

Tags: java, class, field

We are trying to pass the variable `file` to another class.  We are having a problem at these lines:

```
file = (File) item;

        listModel.addElement(file);
```

at the start of the class we declare the field `file` which we thought could be used throughout the whole class.. yet, when we get to the lines mentioned we get the error `file cannot be resolved to a variable`
If we make `file` a local variable the class works, however we cannot pass on the variable `file` onto another class.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FileDragDemo extends JPanel {
    public static File file;
    public static List data;
    public JList list = new JList();


    public FileDragDemo() {
        list.setDragEnabled(true);
        list.setTransferHandler(new FileListTransferHandler(list));

        add(new JScrollPane(list));

    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        FileDragDemo mainPanel = new FileDragDemo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileDragDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //String filestring ="";
        //data = new List;

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
                PdfEasyManager PdfEasyManagerObject = new PdfEasyManager();
                try {
                    PdfEasyManagerObject.main(args);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class FileListTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    public JList list;

    public FileListTransferHandler(JList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }

    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport ts) {
        return ts.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
    }

    public boolean importData(TransferSupport ts) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

            List data = (List) ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(
                    DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            if (data.size() < 1) {
                return false;
            }// close if

            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

            for (Object item : data) {

                file = (File) item;

                listModel.addElement(file);

            } // close for
            //String filestring = file.toString();

            list.setModel(listModel);
            return true;

        }// close try  
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static field `file` is declared in class  `FileDragDemo`. However, the lines in which you are using it are in another class named `FileListTransferHandler`. If you want to access it within methods of this class, you have to qualify the field access with the declaring class: `FileDragDemo.file`.

However, in the code you posted I think using this static variable seems not too elegant, I would use a local variable here. Often static variables can and should be avoided.

Comment: In fact, it's not just in-elegant, it is likely to create memory leaks as the static data are not properlly garbage collected because they are linked to the Class and not to an unused object instance..

Comment: Since keeping the variable local is better, how would you pass it onto another class so it can be used?

Comment: For finding out how: could you explain the role of the variable you would like to declare static in your program? I.e., what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the field `file` from the class where it is declared. You have two classes: `FileDragDemo` declares the field `file`, but the class `FileListTransferHandler` tries to use it. This is indeed supposed to give you the described error.

To solve this problem, you can declare the class `FileListTransferHandler` in the class `FileDragDemo`. To do this, simply close the `}` of the outer class declaration after the inner class declaration, like so:

```
public class FileDragDemo {
    // ...

    class FileListTransferHandler {
        // ...
    }
}
```